# required to call save when using rspec with let and subject syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to get used to the rspec let / subject syntax and I can't figure something out.
I have this spec:

```
describe Permission do
  subject(:permission){FactoryGirl.create(:permission, role: role, branch: branch, user: user)}
  let(:role){FactoryGirl.create(:role, name: 'master')}
  let(:branch){FactoryGirl.create(:branch)}
  let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

  context "role_names_by_user_and_branch" do
    it "should return role names for the given user / branch pair" do
      # permission.save
      Permission.role_names_by_user_and_branch(user, branch).should include(role.name)
    end
  end

end
```

Note the commented out `permission.save`.  If I add that in the test passes.
That's the part I don't understand.  If I'm doing `FactoryGirl.create` that permission
should already be saved, and the query work.

My factory is pretty basic:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :permission do
    user
    branch
    role
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [`subject`](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers/ClassMethods#subject-instance_method) is lazy-loaded, so unless you reference it in your test the block is not evaluated.

This means that even just calling `permission` (rather than `permission.save`) in your test is sufficient to get the behavior you want. Alternately, you can use [`subject!`](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers/ClassMethods#subject!-instance_method), which, according to the docs, is “just like `subject`, except the block is invoked by an implicit before hook.”

Note that `let` behaves the same way and similarly has `let!`.

Comment: Okay makes sense.  I tried to make it work with let! but for whatever reason I didn't think to do subject!  Great explanation, thanks!